# MVC 4 Many to Many

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, many-to-many, viewmodel

I have two tables populated with data. My third table is the related table in the manytomany relationship. This table is empty. I want to populate the third table with values from Table 1 & 2 based on a selection of parameters. Is this possible in MVC 4. I know its possible in web forms with stored procedures.

```
Table 1
ID
Name

Table 2
ID
Address

Table 3
ID
Table1ID
Table2ID
Other Column1
Other Column2
```

I will always have to initially insert new data into table 3 so I can add values to the extra columns.

Comment: ASP.NET MVC won't stopping you doing these kind if tasks. You question seems vague as there is no attempted solution. If you do attempted a solution can you please post it part of the question. This would give us a clear indication on what you trying to achieve, what frameworks/techniques you use specifically.